# Visualforce page accessible for other Salesforce profiles integrated with my software

Tags: apex, visualforce, oauth2

I have my software that is sending data to Salesforce using REST API. This is for now only happening for my Salesforce Profile.

I want other Salesforce profiles to be able to integrate with my software.

I have used oAuth2 authentication to make this happen and it works fine, i receive access token, all good.

Now I have created Visualforce page on my Salesforce profile.

I want all Salesforce profiles integrated with software to be able to access that Visualforce page.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide access to the profiles you want by

1. Going to individual profiles, scroll down to the related list `Enabled Visualforce Page Access`, then click EDIT Button and then select the VF page from the Left to the right list box.
2. You can Go to  Setup->Develop->pages and then click the link `security` beside your VF page and then select the profiles you want to provide access to

Comment: I need this to happen automatically, whoever authenticated successfully through oAuth2 should have access to this page. Also is there a way to display that page in the navigation tabs on salesforce?